# How to flip board in scid?

Tags: software, scid

I am using scid version 4.6.2. How can I flip the board such that I get black's point of view?

There should be a flip button somewhere, but I do not see it:

[image]

I've enabled all toolbar buttons as well:

[image]

Comment: Never used Scid but is it hidden in one of the dropdown menus? If I had designed this UI (which I probably wouldn't have) I might have "Show Blacks POV" as a checkbox in Options or something.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail: Scid's UI wasn't really designed, it sort of happened

Answer (score 9):

So, for future reference, the option is under: `Edit` -> `Setup Start Board...`, or by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>.

**Update:** There is another way! Click on the 'menu' icon below the board (three horizontal bars), then on the what I see as a 'crop' icon (on the far right), and then following menu pops up:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple keyboard shortcut for it: You can just hit the "."-Button, when the board is "active" (you can use the arrow-keys to make or take back a move).

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a list of keyboard shortcuts somewhere? I found one for ScidVsPC but not Scid

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe I have just added the shortcuts at https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/32240